# What is the simplist way to ensure that 2 lists in lisp are the same length?

Tags: lisp

Given 2 lists, I want to ensure that they are the same size, I'm having a tough time with this code. Should I be using variables to do this?

```
(defun samesize (list1 list2)
  (cond (;logic here) T))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both [Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_length.htm) and [elisp](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html#Sequence-Functions) have `length`:

```
(defun samesize (list1 list2)
  (= (length list1) (length list2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion if you want to implemet this yourself.

2 lists are the same size if they are both empty. They are different size if one is empty and the other is not. And if none of these is true, they are of the same size-comparison as those lists sans one element (i.e. their `cdr`-s)

Comment: I think you meant "i.e." not "e.g.". Your answer makes more sense if it's homework.

Comment: Yep, i.e. it is supposed to be. Fixed. And it does smell homeworkiyish to me :)

Comment: homeworkish? lol I guess, it's from work, code from a co-worker that i'm trying to learn lisp from.  I don't have a good "primer"

Comment: @Firoso: Implement @DVK's method then. It'll be more instructive than mine :-).

Answer (score -1):

No need to explicitly use length twice.

```
(defun samesize (l1 l2)
  (apply #'= (mapcar #'length (list l1 l2)))
```

This may seem like wasted effort, but with longer function names this sort of thing is useful.

I was also hoping to demonstrate a new concept.

DRY (don't repeat yourself)